How to split a string with multiple colons in python
An example would be
abc:def:ghi:jkl

How would I code in Python to make it so that only abc is printed?
I know I'd start with
String ="abc:def:ghi:jkl"

But I'm not sure what's next; I'm new to python and regex.

Regex isn't needed. Split the string, optionally once. Get the first element of the list.
s = 'abc:def:ghi:jkl'
first = s.split(':', 1)[0]
print(first)

